# Can open an HTML file with Browser but not HTMLViewer

Tags: motorola-droid-x, file-system, html, 3.2-honeycomb

I have an HTML file on my SD card.  Opening it with "Browser" works as expected. However, if I try to open it with the built-in app "HTMLViewer", I receive the following error message:

> Web page not available
>
> The Web page at *File URI* could not be loaded:
>
> The requested file was not found.

Obviously the file is there since I can open it with Browser.  This was not a problem on Android 2.2.1.

Why can't HTMLViewer open an HTML file?

Comment: Sounds like an app incompatibliity with newer android versions. This question is imho to localized for an.sx - you should ask the app developer for help.

Comment: @Flow pretty sure that "HTMLViewer" is a built-in app, I have it, I've never installed anything with that name, and it has a default Android icon in the "Complete action using" list when I try to open an HTML file on my SD card. On the other hand it is working for me opening an HTML file from /mnt/sdcard/downloads/ on 2.3.3

Comment: @GAThrawn Hmm I havn`t seen that app on my android devices. Does it show the source/plain html?

Comment: @Flow it doesn't show the source, it renders the web page (as best it can) from the .HTML file. It doesn't show in the apps list at all, just shows up as an option when I try to open an HTML file from the file system (along with the "DB HTML Viewer" and "DB Text Editor" that comes with DropBox, and Firefox).

Comment: @Flow GAThrawn is right on. HTMLViewer is a built-in app (I updated the question to say this) and it tries to render the HTML.

Comment: @GAThrawn I also have Dropbox and the BD HTML Viewer.  I can successfully open the HTML file using this program if I navigate to the file. However, I get a similar error message if I create a homescreen shortcut to the file using ASTRO file manager and then try to use DB HTML Viewer to open the file via the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The HTMLViewer mentioned does not like spaces in the file name. Rename the file with underscore or throw them out.